# Error with TKinter Attribute Simpledialog

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

I'm currently trying to write in a few basic user input boxes using the tkinter module in Python 3.6 (via Spyder). I can confirm that the module loads, and that the option to select simpledialog comes up, but I keep getting the following error:

***AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'simpledialog'***

[Image of tkinter simpledialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M10bi.png)

I've tried to look for other options, but other user input options do not seem to work on my Python interface. It either crashes, or the data isn't structured properly.

Interestingly enough, in the past, I've done similar things in Python with no errors, but this keeps coming up with this particular programming piece.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import pyodbc as py
py.pooling = False

## INPUT YOUR USER ID AND PASSWORD AND DECLARE YOUR CONNECTION
## THE DIALOG BOXES MAY POP OPEN ON ANOTHER SCREEN
## THE PASSWORD INPUT IS MASKED AND WILL NOT SHOW IN THE
## VARIABLE EXPLORER

ID = tk.simpledialog.askstring("Please input your username.","Username: ")
PW = tk.simpledialog.askstring("Please input your password.",
                               "Password: ", show='*')
CONN = tk.simpledialog.askstring("Please input your connection.",
                                 "Connection: ")
```

My expected results are that a popup window will appear and that I'll be able to get the user information I need to maintain a stable connection to the server I'm using.

Thank you in advance for your advice!

Comment: Possibly you have a `tkinter.py` file somewhere that is shadowing the actual module.  `import tkinter; print(tkinter.__file__)` will show you where it is.

Comment: I've checked that and I get the location here:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py

In the exploration, I've noticed that the "Lib" part is actually capitalized in the directory itself, whereas Spyder has it in lowercase. I know Python is case-sensitive, so do you think that could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`simpledialog` is not in `tkinter` but in `tkinter.simpledialog` and you have to import it

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.simpledialog

root = tk.Tk() # create main window
#root.iconify() # minimize main window 
root.withdraw() # hide main window 

answer = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Question", 'Your name:')
print(answer)

#root.destroy()  # should work without it
#root.mainloop() # should work without it
```

See [tkinter modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules)

Comment: That seems to have fixed things! Thank you very much.

As a follow-up, I also get a blank popup box when I get my user inputs. It just says tk and has no other inputs/outputs. Is that normal?

The code I executed is this:

```python
...
ID = tksd.askstring("Please input your username.","Username: ")
PW = tksd.askstring("Please input your password.",
                               "Password: ", show='*')
CONN = tksd.askstring("Please input your connection.",
                                 "Connection: ")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: it is normal - it is `Tk()` window (main window). I create it manually but `tkinter` can create it automatically. `simpledialog` was created rather to run from `Tk()`, not as standalone program. You can  minimize main window using `root.iconify()` but you have to create `root` manually `root = tk.Tk()`

Comment: That makes sense. Is there any way that I can have it automatically close after my inputs are acquired? I've tried root.destroy and root.quit, but those don't seem to work for me.

Comment: If I use `root.iconify()` or `root.withdraw()` - which minize window and also remove from bottom bar - then I don't need `root.destroy()` or even I don't need `root.mainloop()`. And it works correctly in terminal on Linux Mint / Python 3.7. If I run the same code in some IDE then it needs `root.destroy()`. So it may depens where it is running.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

root = tk.Tk()

ID = simpledialog.askstring("Please input your username.", "Username: ", parent=root)

root.mainloop()
```

This will keep the popup within the parent window and visible.

Comment: Might be better to format this answer as code